# Scheduled local notification triggered by location [Flutter]

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, notifications, location

I'm trying to schedule local notifications that would fire when the user reaches certain location. I have seen some solutions using background geolocation but that is not what I mean.

I need these notifications to be triggered even when the app is fully closed, kind of what UNLocationNotificationTrigger does on iOS. Is there a way to schedule local notifications not by time but rather by location using Flutter?